Compiling error with specific linker in Clang on M1 Mac - unknown options -T
I am trying to follow a project for editing the kernel for a raspberry pi however I am having trouble building the codebase. The walkthrough I am following is at https://s-matyukevich.github.io/raspberry-pi-os/docs/lesson01/rpi-os.html. I have edited the makefile in order to use clang with specific targets to the raspberry pi hardware. Specifically I am running clang with the options -Dtarget=aarch64-linux-gnu -mcpu=cortex-a72. The makefile then works fine to compile the object files but when trying to build the ELF file I am running into trouble. To work with clang I changed the makefile to run $(ARMGNU)-T src/linker.ld -o $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel8.elf  $(OBJ_FILES) where ARMGNU=clang -Dtarget=aarch64-linux-gnu -mcpu=cortex-a72, and BUILD_DIR and OBJ_FILES are the correct directories. This is giving me the following error,
ld: unknown options: -T 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

which I cannot figure out.
Here is my whole makefile
ARMGNU ?= clang -Dtarget=aarch64-linux-gnu -mcpu=cortex-a72 

COPS = -Wall -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -Iinclude -mgeneral-regs-only 
ASMOPS = -Iinclude 

BUILD_DIR = build
SRC_DIR = src

all : kernel8.img

clean :
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR) *.img 

$(BUILD_DIR)/%_c.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(ARMGNU) $(COPS) -MMD -c $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%_s.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.s
    $(ARMGNU) $(ASMOPS) -MMD -c $< -o $@

C_FILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
ASM_FILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.s)
OBJ_FILES = $(C_FILES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(BUILD_DIR)/%_c.o)
OBJ_FILES += $(ASM_FILES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.s=$(BUILD_DIR)/%_s.o)

DEP_FILES = $(OBJ_FILES:%.o=%.d)
-include $(DEP_FILES)

kernel8.img: $(SRC_DIR)/linker.ld $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(ARMGNU)-T src/linker.ld -o $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel8.elf  $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel8.elf -O binary kernel8.img


and this is the linker script
SECTIONS
{
    .text.boot : { *(.text.boot) }
    .text :  { *(.text) }
    .rodata : { *(.rodata) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    . = ALIGN(0x8);
    bss_begin = .;
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } 
    bss_end = .;
}

Again, both of these were taken/adapted from the github repo I linked above.
Running clang --help I see the -T  option so I'm not sure why it is not processing it correctly. After some research online I have tried changing the command to use the options -T,src/linker.ld, -Wl,-T,src/linker.ld, -Wl -T src/linker.ld but all of these gave the same result that -T was an unknown option. I expected this command to generate the kernel8.elf file but now I don't know what to try. I have tried compiling using the -T option outside of the makefile on a random .o file with clang -T src/linker.ld -o kernel8.elf test.o but got the same error that -T was unknown.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(a) Did you use -v to see the invocation like it told you to? Add -v to the compile command to see the command it used to invoke the linker. (b) Why are you writing $(ARGGNU)-T …? Writing it without a space suggests some attempt to make it part of the command name (like clang-T) rather than an option to the command. (c) Did you find the compile command in the make output to see exactly what command make was executing after it did the variable replacements?

a) Yes, it just said the same error with the -v option. b) that was the way the makefile was set up, I ensured that there was a space after the definition so that it didn’t come out like clang-T. C) yes the compile command that was running and being failed on was ‘clang -Dtarget=aarch64-linux-gnu -mcpu=cortex-a72 -T src/linker.ld -o build/kernel8.elf’ plus various object files.

Clang just passes -T and the text that follows it (apparently whether the text immediately follows -T or is separated by whitespace) to the linker. So it seems your linker does not have a -T switch. The project you are following must be using a different linker.
